# How to user dplyr in functions?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have such problem:
I need a function which will calculate in specified data frame n() by specified columns. Like this:

```
return(df %>% group_by(user_id, date) %>% summarise(n=n()) %>% ungroup())
```

But I dont know how to put part "user_id, date" in function arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Use group_by_, as it takes variables

```
x <- "user_id"
group_by_(x,"date")
```

**For multiple inputs:**

```
x <- list(~user_id, ~date)
df %>% group_by_(.dots = x)
```

Comment: You dropped a ' " '

Comment: but how to user one valiable for "user_id" and "date"? I've tried c("user_id", "date"), got something strange

Comment: @Slavka `dots <- c("user_id", "date"); group_by_(.dots = dots)` perhaps?